# How to get the last word(s) in a paragraph in Python using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am looking for a way to extract the last word in a line. I only want to extract the First name:  Mike
My code is

```
import re

text_to_search = '''
I like Apples and bananas 
I like fruits and yogurt
thisUser: Your name : Mike Lewis
Email: mike@mail.com
type: Fullresopnse
'''
pattern = re.compile(r'thisUser: Your name :\s[A-Z]\w+')

matches = pattern.search(text_to_search)

print(matches)
```

running this code gets me :

```
re.Match object; span=(54, 80), match='thisUser: Your name : Mike'
```

How do I get only `"Mike"` or `"Mike lewis"` to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression has a capturing group that would return Mike:

```
thisUser:\s*Your name\s*:\s*(\S+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q1Dg6D/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"thisUser:\s*Your name\s*:\s*(\S+)"

test_str = ("I like Apples and bananas \n"
    "I like fruits and yogurt\n"
    "thisUser: Your name : Mike Lewis\n"
    "Email: mike@mail.com\n"
    "type: Fullresopnse")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Comment: Hey, excellent thanks for the link to the regex tester as well!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `re.findall` here:

```
matches = re.findall(r'\bYour name\s*:\s*(\S+)\s+(\S+)', text_to_search)
print("first name: " + matches[0][0])
print("last name: " + matches[0][1])
```

This prints:

```
first name: Mike
last name: Lewis
```

The potential advantage of `re.findall` here might be if you expect your text to have more than one name entry in it.